# Is it possible to get the knowledge of Veda by doing any specific vrat/tap

Tags: vedas

I was wondering if there is any kind of yagya/tap/vrat that can be done to get the knowledge of Veda, becuase today all the copies of Veda are not complete and you can not get the true meaning of it even if you read it

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can read about Rishi Daivarata who was sage of recent times. He heard mantras of Rigveda in his meditation and suddenly started speaking it...

Comment: Realize God. He will explain it all to you if you desire.